# Sorting multiple different string in a file to a outputfile

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, grep

I am trying to sort all IPs with the same port into one output file. The issue I am having is that with the syntax I use, a lot of wrong IPs will get in the output file:

```
cat input.txt | grep ":80" > output.port80.txt
```

Content of the input.txt:

```
192.168.1.1:8080
192.168.1.2:80
192.168.1.3:18080
192.168.1.4:808
192.168.1.5:80
...
```

Comment: add a word boundary to your regex pattern: `grep ":80\>" input.txt > output.port80.txt`

Comment: IF you just want `port 80` add a `$` to indicate end, e.g. `grep ':80$' < input > output`  PS, don't `cat input |` that is a *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`). Either use redirection or just `grep` the first file, e.g.  `grep ':80$' input > output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `GNU grep`, you can use:

```
grep -P ':80\b' input.txt > output.port80.txt
```

otherwise, if the file is end in `:port`, use this:

```
grep ':80$' input.txt > output.port80.txt
```

More exactly, if there're white spaces after `:port`,

```
grep ':80[[:space:]]*$' input.txt > output.port80.txt
```

With `awk` however, you can dealing with situations like `192.168.1.7:80THINGSafter`,
and remove the things after the `:port`:

```
awk '(p=index($0, ":80")) && (substr($0,p+3,1) !~ /[0-9]/){print substr($0,1,p+2)}' input.txt > output.port80.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you need to have only those IPs which are ending with `80` port if this is the case then try following.

```
grep '.*:80$' Input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk also

```
$ awk -F: ' /:80$/ { print $0  } ' gerald.log
192.168.1.2:80
192.168.1.5:80

$ awk -F: ' /:80$/ { print $0 > "output." $2 ".log" } ' gerald.log

$ cat  output.80.log
192.168.1.2:80
192.168.1.5:80

$
```